# Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.19.0:test (default-test) : No test Found

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, classpath

I am able to execute `mvn clean install` from maven repository on my machine.

But via jenkin, I get following error:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.19.0:test (default-test): No tests found.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests found.
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.TestMojo.runTest(TestMojo.java:955)
        at org.eclipse.tycho.surefire.TestMojo.execute(TestMojo.java:668)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

`

What is going wrong here?

Comment: \Your configuration is wrong. Cannot help without seeing the relevant contents of pom.xml

Comment: @EinarBjerve: I realized the problem is, I am trying to invoke a specific test from sub-module using -Dtest.

I am running, `mvn clean install` on parent pom to build and run junit, after which I am trying to invoke a specific integration test.

Is it possible to build parent pom followed by running a specific integration test?